# Unix command error

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

when I try this command I'm getting the right path

```
find /home/*/*/*/*.log
```

result is

```
 /home/blross23/karthi/mmw/sample.log
```

But When I try this command

```
find /home/*/*/*/*.log -mtime +1  -type f -size +2  -printf "%s %h%f\n"
```

The result I'm getting is

```
7950 /home/blross23/karthi/mmwsample.log
```

where at the end of the path "/" (mmwsample.log
)is missing between the two directories

correct path is /..../mmw/sample.log
What I'm getting is /..../mmwsample.log

What's the error in the command ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conseider the format in your command:

`find /home/*/*/*/*.log -mtime +1  -type f -size +2  -printf "%s %h%f\n"`

You are specifically telling it to print those two values without a '/' between them.  To correct it, try:

`find /home/*/*/*/*.log -mtime +1  -type f -size +2  -printf "%s %h/%f\n"`